# Yard: incompatible marshal file format (can't be read)

Tags: ruby, yard

I'm getting this when running Yard and then clicking on a file link:

```
incompatible marshal file format (can't be read)
    format version 4.8 required; 114.101 given 
/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/yard-0.8.6.2/lib/yard/registry_store.rb:254:in `load'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Possible that the file you are reading is not Marshaled at all. please check the file once again.